# How to add a php QR code generator script on a Wordpress website as a page

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I just bought this qr code generator php script template from codecanyon.
Here is the details of the script and live demo.
https://codecanyon.net/item/qrcdr-responsive-qr-code-generator/9226839#

I can run this locally on my computer as well as on my server but I want to add blog feature on this website using Wordpress as it’s easier to manage pages and posts with Wordpress.
I believe this is possible as both are built on php.

So basically what I want is a Wordpress website but one of the page should be this php script mentioned above.

How do I achieve this?

I uploaded the php script files and folders in the root directory and added a page in Wordpress with the script’s page embedded as iframe but it does not run as a full standalone page and it runs as a small embedded section of the page.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.